# Bootstrap navbar issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Soruce Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlfTR.png)

[BootStrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUHjQ.png) && [my nav Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJPGX.png)

l went make  my nav like BootStrap

I don't Know why my navbar look like that and how I can Fix this

The Code 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Comment: Code, my man... Code! Add the code so people can help...

Comment: please show us your code too if u need any help with it. Can't say anything without looking at code

Comment: How is it supposed to look? It is not possible to help you without your code. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because of you are using both the latest bootstrap beta version (v4.0.0-beta.3) and earlier bootstrap version (v3.3.7). I believe you have used both the following cdn path.

```
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

If you use the above one, you will end up with the result as you showed in the image. Same you can verify in the [**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hdze4dsm/1/).

The solution is to use the version(v3.3.7) only in your code and you can get the same look and feel as they have showed in bootstrap site. Same you can check in this [**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zy1Lja80/)

**NOTE:** Whenever you post some question in StackOverflow, add minimal running code of your problem, so that people will easily understand your problem and help you to resolved the issue. Only IMAGE won't work for all the time.

Comment: I'm Very thankful For You For This Help It Solved and I  UnderStand This Point I Was'nt No This

And I get It Your Note And Think You For This

Comment: glad to help you. if you feel it really helped you then you can accept this answer and can give up vote also :)

Comment: How I Can Accept Answer